# How to notify view when I change value of some property or delete from list?

Tags: backbone.js

I need to create model which holds css properties for one element. My model looks like this:

```
StyleModel = Backbone.Model.extend( {
    defaults : {
        productName : '',
        styles:{
            'font-weight':'normal',
            'font-style':'normal',
            'text-decoration':'none',
            'visibility':'visible'
            'color':'blue',
            'border-width':'1px',
            'border-color':'white',
            'font-color':'white'
        }
    },
    initialize : function(property, values) {}
...}
```

How to notify view when I change value of some property or delete from list ?
(For example when user set **border-width** to **3px** or when delete **font-weight**. Or is it better solution not to hold properties in hash and to set that every property be element in model ?)

Answer (score 7):

Backbone won't recognize settings in your hash, on it's own. But you can create methods that handle this for you:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  setCss: function(key, value){
    var css = this.get("styles");
    css[key] = value;
    this.trigger("change", this, key, value);
    this.trigger("change:css", key, value);
    this.trigger("change:css:" + key, value);
  }
});
```

Then you would call `model.setCss("background-color", "#ff0faf")` and it would trigger the three "change" events for you to bind to in your views.

In the view, you can bind the change events in the initializer, and have jQuery apply all of the styles to the DOM element that the view controls:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.on("change:css", this.setCss, this);
  },

  setCss: function(){
    var css = this.model.get("styles");
    this.$el.setCss(css);
  }
});
```

You might need to clear existing css before applying the new set, to make sure you get rid of anything that was removed. More likely, though, you'll want to have a `deleteCss` method on the model, have it raise a `css:deleted` event from the model, and have the view respond to that event by removing the css attribute in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you just tell me how to connect this to View (just syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Use the change event that is available on the model http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-change

Have your view bind to the event. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on